# How to invoke specific FFMPEG test?

Tags: ffmpeg, makefile, cmake

I work on LLVM and I'm getting failures for `vsynth-snow-ll`, but I couldn't figure out how that test is invoked individually by looking at the make files. Is anyone familiar with which compiled objects it uses?

This is the FFMPEG Google Benchmarks: https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg

I recon I can do a run of all FFMPEG benches with `build.sh` but that doesn't really give me enough information to debug on. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `make V=2 fate-vsynth1-snow-11` to see the commands that make executes.